# Solving ODE with solve_ivp gets incredibly slow or freezes completely

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I use `solve_ivp` to solve an ODE:

```
def test_ode(t, y):
    dydt = C - y + (y ** 8 / (1 + y ** 8))
    return dydt

steady_state = []
for C in np.linspace(0, 1, 1001):
    sol = solve_ivp(test_ode, [0, 1e06], [0], method='BDF')
    steady_state.append(sol.y[0][-1])
```

This gives me a `RuntimeWarning`:

```
ETA:  --:--:--/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/bdf.py:418: 
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in power
  factors = error_norms ** (-1 / np.arange(order, order + 3))
```

But even worse, the run basically freezes (or at least gets incredibly slow). Replacing the initial value `[0]` by `[1e-08]` does not solve the problem. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why use 1e+6 as quasi-infinity? The solution is settled at 1e+2, all further integration is a balance between accumulation of floating point noise and further convergence. You could just compute the stationary points using an iteration like `y = C+1-1/(1+y**8)` from the start or to refine the solution at time `t=1e2`.

Comment: @LutzL: Thanks, lowering t_max seems to help!!

Comment: That said, that the solver throws such an error on an essentially flat part of the solution should be a bug in `solve_ivp`. The problem can also be solved by reducing `max_step` from the default infinity to something finite like `1e5`. However, for `C` close to 1 the solution seems to be not as flat as expected, the solver slows down, has to take smaller steps, and thus more of them.

Comment: @LutzL: Hi, could you please give me a hint how to compute the stationary points from the start, using the expression `y = C+1-1/(1+y**8)` (your comment from Feb 4)? How did you derive this expression?

Comment: Stationary points are those where `dydt=0`. Now take that equation and transform it into fixed-point form. There are 2 obvious variants, the one I used is contracting, the other not. You could of course also call `scipy.optimize.fsolve` or apply the Newton method directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NumbaLSODA: https://github.com/Nicholaswogan/NumbaLSODA . Its like solve_ivp, but all the code can be compiled. So it is very speedy:

```py
from NumbaLSODA import lsoda_sig, lsoda
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import time

@nb.cfunc(lsoda_sig)
def test_ode(t, y_, dydt, p):
    y = y_[0]
    C = p[0]
    dydt[0] = C - y + (y ** 8 / (1 + y ** 8))
funcptr = test_ode.address

@nb.njit()
def main():
    steady_state = np.empty((1001,),np.float64)
    CC = np.linspace(0, 1, 1001)
    y0 = np.array([0.0])
    for i in range(len(CC)):
        data = np.array([CC[i]],np.float64)
        t_eval = np.array([0.0, 1.0e6])
        sol, success = lsoda(funcptr, y0, t_eval, data = data)
        steady_state[i] = sol[-1,0]
    return steady_state

main()
start = time.time()
steady_state = main()
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

result is 0.013 seconds